# In RESTful API, Are Resources need to be directly in relation to domain models?

Tags: rest, api, swagger, restful-url

Consider I have a User resource on database and it contains a list of Addresses with in it.

```
GET /users -> Returns list of users
[
  {
    "name":"Rick",
    "email":"abc@example.com,
    "addresses":[
      "home" : {
                  ....  
                },
      "work" : {
                  ...
               }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here addresses is a part of User resource. Now when designing api for CRUD on addresses the below seems to be a of good structure.

```
GET /users/{user-id}/addresses
POST /users/{user-id}/addresses
```

But i'm confused as addresses doesn't relate to a direct domain model on database. 
So question is

Are Resources need to be directly in relation with domain models? or above design is proper?

Answer (score 1):

> Are Resources need to be directly in relation with domain models?

No.  In fact, it's been argued that they shouldn't be.

> Your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your affordance model.  -- [Amundsen, 2016](http://amundsen.com/talks/2016-06-wsrest/2016-06-WADM.pdf).

---

> So, GET /users/{user-id}/addresses POST /users/{user-id}/addresses is valid?

It's not clear which question you are asking.

Having a resource that returns representations of a collection of addresses for a user? Sure, there's nothing wrong with doing that.  You may want to think through some of the caching implications -- what happens to cached representations of `/users/{user-id}` when somebody posts a change to `/users/{user-id}/addresses`? -- and make the trade-offs appropriate to your situation.

Are those *identifier spellings* appropriate for a resource?  Sure -- but so are any other ones you might imagine.  REST doesn't care what spelling you use, so long as you are following the appropriate standard (in the case of URI: RFC 3986).

Comment: So,
GET /users/{user-id}/addresses
POST /users/{user-id}/addresses
is valid?